# Why does the text not render on canvas Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm working on a pong copy using pygame. So far everything was working fine with pygame and everything was rendering. I wanted to add the player score to the screen, and I can't get it up. I'm not actually familiar with pygame that much so I pretty muched copied the text code from the docs and other sources. However they would not render, but when I opened a standalone, python file, it worked fine. Here is my main.py file where I render text and a link to the demo using replit: https://replit.com/@Glitchez/Pong-demo?v=1

```
import pygame
from paddles import *
from controls import *
from ball import *
pygame.font.init() 
# SCREEN INIT
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

# VARIABLES
ball_radius = 7
paddle_speed = 5
paddle_length = 100
FPS = 60

# DEFINE OBJECTS
paddle1 = Paddle(paddle_length, 15, 100, paddle_speed, True, WHITE)
paddle2 = Paddle(paddle_length, 970, 100, paddle_speed, False, WHITE)
ball = Ball(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2, ball_radius)
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)


# COLLISION MANAGEMENT
def handle_collision(ball, paddle1, paddle2):
    if ball.y + ball.radius >= HEIGHT:
        ball.y_vel *= -1
    elif ball.y - ball.radius <= 0:
        ball.y_vel *= -1

    if ball.x_vel < 0:
        if paddle1.y <= ball.y <= paddle1.y + paddle1.height:
            if ball.x - ball.radius <= paddle1.x + paddle1.width:
                ball.x_vel *= -1

                middle_y = paddle1.y + paddle1.height / 2
                difference_in_y = middle_y - ball.y
                reduction_factor = (paddle1.height / 2) / ball.MAX_VEL
                y_vel = difference_in_y / reduction_factor
                ball.y_vel = -1 * y_vel
    else:
        if paddle2.y <= ball.y <= paddle2.y + paddle2.height:
            if ball.x + ball.radius >= paddle2.x:
                ball.x_vel *= -1

                middle_y = paddle2.y + paddle2.height / 2
                difference_in_y = middle_y - ball.y
                reduction_factor = (paddle2.height / 2) / ball.MAX_VEL
                y_vel = difference_in_y / reduction_factor
                ball.y_vel = -1 * y_vel



# HANDLE ALL GRAPHICS
def graphics(screen):
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    paddle1.draw(screen)
    paddle2.draw(screen)
    ball.draw(screen)
    # DRAWS DOTTED LINE
    for i in range(10, HEIGHT, HEIGHT // 20):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            continue
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (WIDTH // 2 - 5, i, 8, HEIGHT // 40))


# GAME LOOP
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE = 0, 0
    #ISSUE HERE!!!
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
    text_surface = my_font.render(str(P1_SCORE), False, (255, 255, 255))
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        win.blit(text_surface, (250,250))
        paddle1.move()
        paddle2.move()
        ball.move()
        handle_collision(ball, paddle1, paddle2)
        P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE = ball.check_win(P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE)
        graphics(win)
        pygame.display.update()
        print(f"player 1: {P1_SCORE}, player 2: {P2_SCORE}")
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service or a help desk; we require a *specific* question that emerges from your best attempt to diagnose and isolate the problem. We should be able to copy and paste the code example in order to see the problem directly, without any other functionality; and we should be able to see your existing understanding of the problem. "However they would not render, but when I opened a standalone, python file, it worked fine." is not a clear description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is rendering the score correctly, `blit()`ing it to the window perfectly... but then erasing everything when the screen is painted in `graphics()`.

So, you have a function `graphics()`, move the score-drawing into there.

```
# HANDLE ALL GRAPHICS
def graphics(screen, font, p1_score, p2_score):
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    paddle1.draw(screen)
    paddle2.draw(screen)
    ball.draw(screen)
    # DRAWS DOTTED LINE
    for i in range(10, HEIGHT, HEIGHT // 20):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            continue
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (WIDTH // 2 - 5, i, 8, HEIGHT // 40))
    # DRAWS THE SCORE
    # PLAYER 1  (LEFT)
    text_surface = my_font.render(str(p1_score), False, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (250,250))
    # PLAYER 2  (RIGHT)
    text_surface = my_font.render(str(p2_score), False, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (WIDTH-WIDTH//4,250))  # 25% from the right-side

# GAME LOOP
def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE = 0, 0
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        paddle1.move()
        paddle2.move()
        ball.move()
        handle_collision(ball, paddle1, paddle2)
        P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE = ball.check_win(P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE)
        graphics(win, my_font, P1_SCORE, P2_SCORE)
        pygame.display.update()
        print(f"player 1: {P1_SCORE}, player 2: {P2_SCORE}")
    pygame.quit()
```

NOTE: This is not tested code, errors and omissions should be expected.

If the text-rendering becomes slow, you could also pre-render all the scores to an array of surfaces on start-up. Then just blit the one that matches the score.